# while trying uploaing nothing is happening

Tags: file-upload, node.js

i want to upload a file by node.js so i try by this article. 
http://debuggable.com/posts/parsing-file-uploads-at-500-mb-s-with-node-js:4c03862e-351c-4faa-bb67-4365cbdd56cb

I run  this code

```
var formidable = require('formidable')
  , http = require('http')
  , sys = require('sys');

var server=http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log('out if condition'+sys.inspect(req));
  if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    // parse a file upload
    console.log('in if condition');
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(sys.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end
    ( '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'
    + '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'
    + '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'
    + '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'
    + '</form>'
    );
});
server.listen(8000);
```

when i upload the file it doesn't proceed further easily and doesn't go in if condition of upload why ?

Comment: Can you give more details regarding your error?

Comment: when i comment these lines res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(sys.inspect({fields: fields, files: files})); then it print console.log ,and for copying files to server what i need to do ?

Comment: @stephen actually it is not going in node after upload button click in browser , what is happening ?

Comment: @Stephen Yeah input form is showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 fs.writeFile(files.upload.name, files.upload,'utf8', function (err) {
                      if (err) throw err;
                      console.log('It\'s saved!');
                });
```

Please check.

http://rahulmehta1.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/uploading-a-file-in-node-js-by-formidable/